# Which TCP window update is most recent?

Tags: tcp

I was writing a TCP implementation, did all the fancy slow and fast retransmission stuff, and it all worked so I thought I was done. But then I reviewed my packet receive function (almost half of the 400 lines total code), and realized that my understanding of basic flow control is incomplete...

Suppose we have a TCP connection with a "sender" and "receiver". Suppose that the "sender" is not sending anything, and the receiver is stalling and then unstalling.

Since the "sender" is not sending anything, the "receiver" sees no ack_no delta. So the two window updates from the "receiver" look like:

1. ack_no = X, window = 0
2. ack_no = X, window = 8K

since both packets have the same ack_no, and they could be reordered in transit, how does the sender know which came first?

If the sender doesn't know which came first, then, after receiving both packets, how does it know whether it's allowed to send?

One guess is that maybe the window's upper endpoint is never allowed to decrease? Once the receiver has allocated a receive buffer and advertised it, it can never un-advertise it? In that case the window update could be reliably handled via the following code (assume no window scale, for simplicity):

```
  // window update  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931135/)
  int ack_delta = pkt_ack_no - c->tx_sn_ack;
  c->tx_window  = MAX(BE16(PKT.l4.window), c->tx_window - ack_delta);
  if (c->tx_window)
    Net_Notify(); // wake up transmission
```

But this is terrible from a receiver standpoint: it vastly increases the memory you'd need to support 10K connections reliably. Surely the protocol is smarter than that?

Comment: 'It vastly increases the memory' how? All it needs is the socket receive buffer, and it already has that.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I'm not sure what you mean by "it already has that" -- I am implementing "it" so I don't have to waste memory if the protocol doesn't require it. But to answer your question, if window can't be retracted, and my (roundtrip time) x (bandwidth) is 10MB, and if I have 10K connections, then I need 100GB of buffer... or I can't ever allow all the bandwidth on one connection (because if it stops suddenly and never starts again, then I can never free that 10MB).

Comment: Part of what you have to implement is a socket receive buffer. That *is* the receive window that is being advertised, or rather the free space in it is. Every connected TCP socket has one (and every UDP socket).

Comment: @Marquis of Lome. Yes, the receive window is advertising a buffer. If the window endpoint can't ever retract, then the buffer can't retract. That is precisely what my example is about. I'm not sure why you don't see how this vastly increases the memory requirements vs. what they would be if the buffer were allowed to retract on idle connections. I have walked through the example in detail.

Comment: I don't know why you don't see that the buffer *is* the receive window, and that implementing it isn't optional. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, I don't see what's unclear. I never said the buffer isn't the receive window. I walked through the troublesome example. You get 2 ack packets that set different receive window sizes. How do you know which one wins? Do you assume that the receive window can't ever shrink? I've spelled out the question very clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an assumption that the receive buffer never shrinks, which is intentionally undocumented to create an elite "skin in the game" club in order to limit the number of TCP implementations.

The [original standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793) says that shrinking the window is "discouraged" but doesn't point out that it can't work reliably:

> The mechanisms provided allow a TCP to advertise a large window and
> to   subsequently advertise a much smaller window without having
> accepted   that much data.  This, so called "shrinking the window," is
> strongly   discouraged.

Even worse, the standard is actually missing the MAX operation proposed in the question, and just sets the window from the most recent packet if the acknowledgement number isn't increasing:

> ```
>       If SND.UNA < SEG.ACK =< SND.NXT, the send window should be
>       updated.  If (SND.WL1 < SEG.SEQ or (SND.WL1 = SEG.SEQ and
>       SND.WL2 =< SEG.ACK)), set SND.WND <- SEG.WND, set
>       SND.WL1 <- SEG.SEQ, and set SND.WL2 <- SEG.ACK.
>
>       Note that SND.WND is an offset from SND.UNA, that SND.WL1
>       records the sequence number of the last segment used to update
>       SND.WND, and that SND.WL2 records the acknowledgment number of
>       the last segment used to update SND.WND.  The check here
>       prevents using old segments to update the window.
> ```

so it will fail to grow the window if packets having the same ack number are reordered.

Bottom line: implement something that actually works robustly, not what's in the standard.